# Is visual studio optimised for hyper-threaded microprocessors?

Tags: multithreading, performance, visual-studio, compiler-optimization, hyperthreading

**I would like to know whether the most common software development suits such as Microsoft visual studio its compilers are optimized for using the Hyper-Threading feature to the maximum extent? Is it worthy to go for a hyper-threaded processor for working with those softwares?**

I have read many reviews that hyper threading is only useful for intensive multi threaded applications like video editors,etc..Some reviews says that softwares which are not optimized for using Hyper threading can suffer a decrease in performance and many people  run their systems with hyper threading turned off.

As I am a novice programmer I would like to know whether those arguments and reviews stands true in the field of programming.

Again I am talking about the compilers and IDE and not the applications that I 'am going to create!(as if now I don't know how to create multi-threaded applications!!)

Comment: as far as an OS is concerned a hyper-thread CPU is just another CPU. stop worrying about largely inconsequential details. If your apps uses threads then they will run on other cores, if cores are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not made up your mind on what IDE/development platform to use then there may be other factors to consider besides threading. Most high level languages and compilers do support **thread pooling**, which is probably what you are looking for. I can't speak for compilers I have not used so I will leave a link to the article below:

[.Net and hyper threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300701.aspx)

It appears to be a bit dated, but the basic concepts are explained.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know...thanks

Comment: It is really out date, some stuff is still true. The first hyper threading are using the same concepts as to days cpus. The pipeline and prediction is far better as a p4 from 2005. In 2005 most programs were still 32bit...